# How do I get the correct display on a precipitation radar

Tags: http-status-codes

I have found an online radar that I want to use for my site. I do this in an iframe. the radar is on the USA but I want this for the Netherlands, but that won't work.

This is the link I want use:
https://www.wndu.com/templates/2015_Fullscreen_Radar?v=2 &memberId=1167&mapId=0023&templateId=0011& latitude=52.005&longitude=5.55&zoomLevel=7&menuItems=0000,2C0000,2C0001,2C00002,2C0009,2C0010,2C0014,2C0017

The ID etc. match, but it doesn't work. Someone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That [website](https://www.wndu.com) seems to be using an inactive api (api.weather.com)
Then they used Mapbox api and OpenStreetMap to show the radar.
You could use a simpler solution like [this](https://openweathermap.org/api).